# How to use window.open with state data (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to replace history.push to window.open (to of course open in a new tab). I tried to use query params to access my state's data to be fetched in the new tab.

`` window.open(`/${db}/endpoint?var1=${link.var1}&var2=${link.var2}`) ``

Anyone has a tip for this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Are you doing anything on the new page to load the state from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you use window.open then the script will be loaded from scratch in a new tab (will not be connected to the previous tab in anyway), so either you have to load data from local storage if you want to share some data between sessions or tabs.